# A $3\times3$ matrix with rank 2 must have a nonzero solution to $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have recently come across the following statement:

A $3\times3$ matrix A with rank $2$ **must** have a nonzero solution to $Ax=0.$

I am having trouble understanding why there **must** be a nonzero solution to $Ax = 0.$ Is it due to the fact that we will have a free variable?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to see it: we will have a free variable, which means we will have a non-zero solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the rank of a matrix is 2 then, by the Rank-Nullity theorem, the kernel must have dimension 1.

Comment: Just for clarification: If the kernel has dimension 1, that implies that $Ax = 0$ has infinitely many solutions dependent on one variable?

Comment: As @Oiler mentioned in another answer, this technically depends on the field.  If I assume that you are working over the real or complex numbers, then yes, there are infinitely many solutions which can be parametrized by one parameter: let $v\in V$ be a non-zero solution to $Av =0 $. Then $\{\alpha v\colon \alpha \in \mathbb{R} (\mbox{ or } \mathbb{C})\} = \mathrm{ker} A$, and so the null space is parametrized by $\alpha$. (Note that this $\alpha$ corresponds precisely to the "free parameter" you would get from row reducing, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you inspect the row echelon form, you get a zero row and hence there is $1$ free parameter.

In fact, you obtain infinitly many non-zero solutions.

Comment: Infinitely many non-zero solutions is true only if you are working over an infinite field.

Comment: @Oliver, I agree, I was assuming $\mathbb{C}$ just now.

Answer (score 1):

What is your definition of rank? If rank of matrix is defined as maximal number of it's linearly independent columns, from this we immediately get that columns $c_1,c_2,c_3$ of matrix $A$ must be linearly dependent whenever $\operatorname{rank}(A)<3$. This means that 
$$\lambda_1 c_1 + \lambda_2 c_2 + \lambda_3 c_3 = A \left[ \begin{matrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3 \end{matrix} \right] = 0$$
for some $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 \neq 0$.